# Performance issue of games running at different percentages of battery

Tags: windows-10, battery, nvidia-geforce

I brought this laptop about 2 months ago.The problem im facing is when i run games at 100 % charged battery, the games lag but when the battery decreases to 60 % from there onwards the games run just fine as they are expected. It would be great if anyone helps me with the problem.

- HP Pavilion - 15-au114tx
- 7th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-7200U Processor
- Windows 10 Home
- 8GB DDR4 RAM
- 1TB HDD
- 15.6" screen
- NVIDIA® GeForce® 940MX

Answer (score 0):

check the power options from the windows - theres different ones for charging and not-charging. also if the battery is LI-ION there might be a fire protection stuff as the LI-ION batteries can catch fire if power is overdrawn.

also the manufacturers make up some weird limitations for the GPU/CPUs, especially on the gaming laptops.